# Copy format from one column range to another column range in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have an excel sheet with 8 rows and 4096 columns.I am trying to find the top 4 values of each column and highlight them.I can do this for one column by using conditional formatting and copy format to the next column but its not possible for 4096 columns.Is there a macro or any other way to highlight top 4 values in each column?

Comment: Why can't you copy conditional formatting across? if you remove the $ from the address, then it should amend the ranges for you. Use paste special, and select formats only.

Comment: I am not using any formula there is a predefined option to highlight top n items

Comment: ^^ I ment conditional formats. You must be specifying ranges in your statement? Just remove the $ , and copy / paste special. If there is no addresses, what does copy / pasting all the formats across do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Excel's **conditional formatting** with the *Top 10 items...* feature

- Select column A
- Call the top 10 items feature
- Set the top number to 4 and set your conditional formatting for the cell

Column A now highlights the top 4 values
Now clone this with the Format Painter tool:

- Select column A
- Click on the Format Painter button
- Click on column B to apply the formatting the same way as A
- Repeat the operation for column C to H, one column after another

Now your columns have all the correct formatting. If you select your table you will get a conditional formatting rule list like this:

[image]

Comment: I guess you did not read the part where it says my table contain 4096 columns

Comment: I read 8 columns. Nevertheless, if this is your issue, then start recording a macro with relative reference when you apply my methodology to format-paint column B from column A. Then you will get a trivial VBA macro that clones the format of a current column to the next one. Thus you can run this VBA code in a loop from 1 to 4096 and you're done.

Comment: I have never written or used a Macro.Can you give any references for the same?

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-macro-HP010342374.aspx#BMrecordmacro